# After adding code into a new thread, why do the graphics break so dramatically?

Tags: multithreading, performance, processing, frame-rate, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to write Conway's Game Of Life but came into an issue of the framerate and how quickly each generation is generated. I was recommended by a friend to try threading to increase the framerate but I came into an issue. 
I added a thread to run the checking and changing of the cells and it now has huge graphical problems.
[This image shows the issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0eCU.jpg) It should be a 50x50 grid of these grey and white cells.

The threading is the issue as before I added this all was working fine, this is the first time I have attempted threading, complete beginner.

[Github link to all of my code.](https://github.com/FrederickTheIII/conwaysGame.git)

Thank you for all of your help, Michael.

Comment: Rather than just linking to your code and expecting us to work out for ourselves where you're going wrong, have you done any debugging? Have you been able to narrow it down to a particular piece of code? Most of the time you should be able to answer your own question from a bit of a thorough debugging session. Without any indication of where you're having the problem or what might be causing it, we'd just be stabbing in the dark - therefore, your question in its current state is very broad and it's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I forgot to mention a couple of things that I did look at, sorry. I'll update the question and descripting when I get the chance, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please don't delete questions after they've been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a link to your entire codebase. Note that this should **not** be your entire project; it should be a small example that demonstrates the problem. In your case, a simple program that uses two threads to draw circles would be enough.

But speaking generally, I can explain why multithreading is buggy with rendering. Processing uses a single thread to handle all of its drawing (and all of its events). This is by design, and isn't something you want to try to get around. Here's why:

Consider an example program that uses two threads: one that uses a nested `for` loop to fill every pixel with red, and another that uses a nested `for` loop to fill every pixel with blue. The first thread goes to the first pixel, turns it red, goes to the second pixel, turns it red, etc. But at the same time, the other thread is going to the first pixel, turning it blue, going to the second pixel, turning it blue, etc.

Here's some code that does exactly that:

```
size(1000, 1000);
noSmooth();
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        point(x, y);
      }
    }
  }
}
.start();

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    stroke(0, 0, 255);
    point(x, y);
  }
}
```

What should the final result look like?

There isn't any single correct answer, and it's going to depend on the execution order of the threads, which you have no control over. Generally you'll get pretty random looking results as the threads "fight" over what should be drawn to the screen:

[image: red and blue]

This makes multithreading pretty useless for rendering.

If you really really want to use threads (and I'm very skeptical that they'd help you very much anyway), then the best you can do is use another thread to calculate the next generation, while the current generation is being drawn. You should do absolutely zero drawing from the second thread, and all of your drawing should be done from the default thread that Processing uses to call the `draw()` function.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the respose, very informative. And secondly, I apologise for the lack of an MCVE, I'm extremely inexperienced with StackOverflow. In future I'll take more time with the response. I'll look over what has been said and do some more digging. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MichaelStaig Please see my edited answer for a concrete example.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. The instructions aren't in the order that you'd expect them to be. That really helps, thank you once again